# Store css data in django db

Tags: python, django

Hi I have a scenario where user inputs css data in text box,  I need to read it and apply it to a django view. I also need to store the css data for future modifications by user.

So my question is 
1.should I store the css data in database or
2.in a static css file and store path to file in db?

Thanks.

Comment: store path will be easiser than storing th css. or you can pickle the css and store it db

Comment: @sundarnatarajСундар CSS is just text. You needn't pickle it. In fact there is nothing easier than storing CSS in DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely no problem with storing CSS in DB. Just create a `TextField` in your model and put it there.

Then in your view's template output it in a `<style type="text/css">` tag and that's all.